# How to Load XML String as CLOB using SQLLDR in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have a flat file with 5 Columns

```
COL1; COL2; COL3; COL4; COL5;
1;Juvanes, NAC1, GLENFENT ST1, <?xml version="1.0"?>.......</End>
2;Puvanes, NAC2, GLENFENT ST2, <?xml version="1.0"?>.......</End>
3;Suvanes, NAC3, GLENFENT ST3, <?xml version="1.0"?>.......</End>
4;Duvanes, NAC4, GLENFENT ST4, <?xml version="1.0"?>.......</End>
5;Muvanes, NAC5, GLENFENT ST5, <?xml version="1.0"?>.......</End>
```

Table Format

```
Create Table Test1(COL1 Number, COL2 VARCHAR(50), COL3 VARCHAR(50), COL4 VARCHAR(50), XML_COL5  CLOB);
```

How to write a Control File to process the sample data in Oracle through SQLLDR.

Comment: Is that supposed to be a csv file? If so, it mixes ";" and "," as separators.

Comment: Its a flat file, Header is separated by ';' and data columns are separated by ','. No need to worry about header column.